# Jetpack Compose: LocalComposition.current

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm looking at the [NowInAndroid](https://github.com/android/nowinandroid) app, Google's Jetpack Compose sample app. In MainActivity, a calculateWindowSize method is called, which invokes `LocalConfiguration.current`.

What is this `LocalConfiguration.current` call for? We're not using the return value.

```
@ExperimentalMaterial3WindowSizeClassApi
@Composable
fun calculateWindowSizeClass(activity: Activity): WindowSizeClass {
    // Observe view configuration changes and recalculate the size class on each change. We can't
    // use Activity#onConfigurationChanged as this will sometimes fail to be called on different
    // API levels, hence why this function needs to be @Composable so we can observe the
    // ComposeView's configuration changes.
    
    LocalConfiguration.current // WHAT DOES THIS DO?

    val density = LocalDensity.current
    val metrics = WindowMetricsCalculator.getOrCreate().computeCurrentWindowMetrics(activity)
    val size = with(density) { metrics.bounds.toComposeRect().size.toDpSize() }
    return WindowSizeClass.calculateFromSize(size)
}
```

Comment: It triggers recomposition on configuration change

Answer (score 0):

The comment above the call is trying to explain why this is done.

Just reading the value of `LocalConfiguration.current` will ensure this method is invoked whenever the configuration changes. The code below this call uses this indirect notification to calculate the new window size class based on the new configuration. WindowMetricsCalculator is not directly observable as it is independent of Compose. The result of calling `calculateFromSize()` could change whenever the configuration changes so the call to `LocalConfiguration.current` ensure this method is called whenever the result could change.